# Is it possible to call hook after Login in WordPress & save the user_pass to a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.0

I know Wordpress has hooks to do some before or after events such as logging, is it possible to run a hook after login to gain the password & store to a session

```
function do_anything() {
  //do stuff
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
```

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**wp_authenticate_user**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user)
`$password` holds the original password entered by user when click on login you can store it into `sessions`.

I've added `die('call');` for checking the password, Don't forget to remove it.

As Stated in Docs

> The `wp_authenticate_user` filter hook is used to perform additional
>   `validation/authentication` any time a user logs in to WordPress.

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'my_auth_login',10,2);
function my_auth_login ($user, $password) {

     //do any extra validation stuff here

    echo '<pre>';print_r($password);echo '</pre>';die('Call');

     return $user;
}
```

Comment: Note to others: This doesn’t necessarily means the user has successfully logged in. This will fire even if password is wrong.